# Why does jest not call my mock implementation

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I have read every SO question and every scrap of documentation on Jest, but I still have no clue why Jest appears to not use my mock implementation at all.

1. The code I am testing does actually work as expected.
2. I am trying to mock XMLHttpRequest.
3. I want to share my mock across multiple unit tests.

I am not sure if I should be following the instructions on mocking ES6 classes. XMLHttpRequest is a method of the window object and not really a class, but a class is just a function that returns an object, so maybe XMLHttpRequest is a class after all.

Since I want to share my mock, I think it fits the pattern for a manual mock, except that XMLHttpRequest is not a module, and it looks like manual mocks only apply to modules.

So this is the mock that I wrote:

```js
function mainMock() {
  let readyState = 4;
  let status = 200;
  let statusText = 'OK';
  let responseText = 'mocked data';
  let response = {};
  let error = null;

  const open = jest.fn();
  const onreadystatechange = jest.fn();
  const send = jest.fn(function send() {
    if (error) throw error;
    this.onreadystatechange();
  });

  const addEventListener = jest.fn(function addEventListener(e, c) {
    this.onreadystatechange = c;
  });

  function setStatus(newStatus = 200, newStatusText = 'OK', newReadyState = 4) {
    status = newStatus;
    statusText = newStatusText;
    readyState = newReadyState;
  }

  function setResponseText(newResponseText) {
    responseText = newResponseText;
    response = {};
  }

  function setResponse(newResponse) {
    responseText = JSON.stringify(newResponse);
    response = newResponse;
  }

  function setError(newError) {
    error = newError;
  }

  function cleanUp() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      delete window.XMLHttpRequest;
    }
  }

  // mock constructor that will replace window XMLHttpRequest
  function mockConstructor() {
    return {
      readyState,
      status,
      statusText,
      responseText,
      response,
      open,
      onreadystatechange,
      addEventListener,
      send,
    };
  }

  // override/define XMLHttpRequest
  window.XMLHttpRequest = mockConstructor;

  return {
    open,
    onreadystatechange,
    addEventListener,
    cleanUp,
    setStatus,
    setResponseText,
    setResponse,
    setError,
    send,
  };
}

export default mainMock;
```

And this is my (abbreviated) unit test

```js
import XMLHttpRequestMock from '~mocks/XMLHttpRequestMock';
import { Service } from './Service';

let mockXMLHttpRequest;
beforeEach(() => {
  mockXMLHttpRequest = XMLHttpRequestMock();
});

afterEach(() => {
  mockXMLHttpRequest.cleanUp();
});

describe('Service', () => {
  it('should-ping', async () => {
    mockXMLHttpRequest.setResponse({
      meta: { version: 99 },
      data: {},
    });

    const service = new Service();
    const meta = await service.ping();
    expect(mockXMLHttpRequest.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(mockXMLHttpRequest.send).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(meta.version).toEqual(99);
    expect(meta.status).toEqual(200);
  });
});
```

The class I am testing definitely makes calls to the `open` and `send` methods because it actually works and pulls back data from the server, but `expect(mockXMLHttpRequest.open)` fails and so do all of the other `expect` calls if I put them first. It appears as though Jest is simply not using the mock at all.

Where do i go from here?

To complete the picture, this is a slightly cut down version of the class I am testing.

```js
import configVars from '~config/configVars';
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime.js';

export class Service {
  constructor(logger) {
    this.logger = logger || console;
  }

  _getJson(request) {
    const _this = this;
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.responseType = request.responseType || 'json';
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
          if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
            resolve(this);
          } else {
            let e = {
              status: this.status,
              statusText: this.statusText,
            };
            reject(e);
          }
        }
      };
      let url = configVars.service.url + request.url;
      xhttp.open('GET', url, true);
      xhttp.setRequestHeader('Accept', request.accept || 'application/json');
      try {
        xhttp.send();
      } catch (e) {
        reject(e);
      }
    });
  }

  async ping() {
    try {
      let xhttp = await this._getJson({ url: 'ping' });
      let meta = xhttp.response.meta;
      meta.status = xhttp.status;
      meta.statusText = xhttp.statusText;
      return meta;
    } catch (e) {
      e.messages = e.messages || [];
      e.messages.push('Ping of service failed');
      return e;
    }
  }
}

export default Service;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of head scratching and trying to figure out how to get the VS Code debugger to step through a Jest test, I finally tracked this down to something quite simple.

I didn't mock `setRequestHeader`, which caused my class to throw an exception before the `send` method was called.